# Duplicate connected app found

Tags: connected-apps

I had a **local connected app** TEMP_Dev.I have **same name connected app in my package** also. When i tried to install my package in that org **package installation got failed** and i got error

> TEMP_DEV: duplicate value found:  duplicates value on record
>   with id:

**So i deleted the local connected app but still whenever i try to install package i get the same error.**

I have emptied my Recycle bin also.

**EDIT**

I just found that even after deleting the connected app we can not reuse its name.
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=connected_app_edit.htm

Do i have any other option??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this official documentation **connected app name can be reused**

[Help - Create a Connected App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_create.htm&type=5#basicinfo)

> NOTE The connected app name must be unique for the connected apps in
> your org. **You can reuse the name of a deleted connected app if the
> connected app was created using the Spring ’14 release or later**.

The original issue seems to be in that you, indeed, tried to install the same connected app from a package. You may want to try creating a new dev org and install your package there.

Comment: Hmm, It seems they indeed made some changes. I still have to confirm though but selecting it as best answer.